# Nuxt 3 'Vue: Cannot find name computed' error for PyCharm IDE

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pycharm, nuxt.js, eslint

I'm developing a project with Nuxt 3 for learning fundamentals. I am using PyCharm IDE and have encountered an issue.

**Issue Description:**

`const userName = computed(() => store.user.name)`

In my Vue components, when I use the computed property(or ref, reactive, onMounted etc.), PyCharm displays on hovering over computed: `Vue: Cannot find name computed`

This issue resolves when I manually import computed from 'vue' `import { computed } from 'vue'`, but as I understand, this shouldn't be necessary in Nuxt 3, which automatically imports these APIs.

**Current `tsconfig.json` Configuration:**

```
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["@nuxt/types", "@types/node"],
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.d.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**Attempts to resolve:**

- Ensured Vue plugin is up to date in PyCharm(Also PyCharm is).
- Invalidate Caches/Restart in PyCharm.
- Delete and reinstall dependencies with cleaning yarn cache

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I suspect the problem might be related to the tsconfig.json configuration or how PyCharm interprets Vue 3/Nuxt 3 projects.

How can I configure PyCharm or my project settings to recognize Vue 3 features like computed without having to import them explicitly in a Nuxt 3 project? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

**Attempts to resolve:**

- Ensured Vue plugin is up to date in PyCharm(Also PyCharm is).
- Invalidate Caches/Restart in PyCharm.
- Delete and reinstall dependencies with cleaning yarn cache